# Selenium click when page zoomed out by 67%

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In selenium, I have to zoom out the page page by 67%. When the page is zoomed out, the locators do not locate the web elements properly and the actions are failing.
How can I form click, select, send values, etc. to fields after zooming out the page?
I have tried `move_by_offset and move_to_element_With_offset` as well, but not working:

```
c_oprtr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"<xpath>")
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
loc = c_oprtr.location
print(loc)

#I get the x and y coordinates from above

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(c_oprtr, 260, 784).click().perform()
#ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(260, 784).click().perform()
```

I have tried move_by_offset and `move_to_element_With_offse`t as well, but not working.
I have also tried "`elementfrompoint`":

```
element=driver.execute_script("return 
document.elementFromPoint(261,794)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the element to be *visible* and *clickable*.

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='67%'")
```

Wait for the web `element`.

```
c_oprtr = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "<xpath>")))
```

Click on the web `element`.

```
c_oprtr.click()
```

***Import***

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Had tried that too, didn't work

#ex_wait1=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((<xpath>")))

Comment: _didn;t work_ ? What `error` are you getting ?

Comment: The error message is something like this:
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button>...</button> is not clickable at point (1484, 540)`
It seems that the position of the element is miscalculated when zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

try doing a JavaScript Click

```
c_oprtr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"<xpath>")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", c_oprtr)
```